# How to configure a drop in ASP.NET "plugin"

Tags: asp.net, iis, plugins, configuration

We're developing a plugin for ASP.NET web apps that can, ideally, be dropped into the folder that makes up the public facing part of our client's web site, i.e. a `foo.aspx` file that becomes publicly accessible at, say, `/foo.aspx` (and can thus be accessed by our browser component written in JS and loaded into the client's website).

However, we need something we're not really sure how to do idiomatically, which is the ability to pass a few configuration parameters to `foo.aspx` in a way that, preferrably, reuses whatever configuration mechanism our client's already using (we're assuming a sufficiently recent version of IIS) or at least something that's considered standard and can be applied to any IIS deployment.

Is IIS metabase something to look at? We need a way to pass in an SSL client certificate file (or path thereof) to `foo.aspx` so that it can talk back to our HTTP REST API via a secure channel. It's also not entirely obvious where's a good and standard disk location to drop the certificate file itself to.

Comment: You might look into how [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) and [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/Docs/) add `/elmah.axd` and `/glimpse.axd` routes to the sites they're installed on, plug and play style.